# Can I move a flat of Spotted Dead Nettle outside in cold temperatures?

Tags: plant-care, seedlings, temperature, cold-weather

I have rooted many cuttings in a flat in late fall.  It is Spring now in Ohio and I would like to repurpose the flat.  If I pot up these young plants, can I move them outside if just above freezing temperatures occur?  The established spotted nettle is doing great in the freezing temperatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you would need to harden them off first. The plants inside are accustomed to warmer conditions, and will not respond well to being placed outdoors in much colder conditions; your existing deadnettle outdoors is obviously already well adapted to cold conditions.

Stand them outside for an hour or two in the middle of the day, then bring them back inside - increase the daily time you leave them out over two weeks so they gradually acclimatise, until they are out all night, but don't choose a freezing cold night, choose a milder one. By then they should be hardened off and can be left outside.

Comment: I have hardened them off for a few weeks and they are now outside in temps down to 40/45 F.  I am going to now put them in the ground even though it may reach freezing.